# Remove compiler warning for a certain directory

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

I enabled `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to see all the warning in my project, but I'm also using a 'library' (I copy/pasted the source code of the library in a folder `libs` of my project) which pops up a lot of warnings.  The code comes with a book (OpenGL Super Bible 5), and I'm using it to learn OpenGL.  However I don't want to see all the warnings generated by this code, only the warnings in my `src` folder.

Is there a way to hide warnings coming from a specific folder?

**I do not try to hide MY warnings, I just want to remove the author's warning so that I can concentrate on fixing my own warnings.**

The warnings are

```
./libs/src/GLTools.cpp:123:6: warning: unused parameter ‘szArgv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
In file included from ./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:36:0:
./libs/include/GLBatch.h: In constructor ‘GLBatch::GLBatch()’:
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:123:16: warning: ‘GLBatch::nNumTextureUnits’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:122:16: warning:   ‘GLuint GLBatch::nNumVerts’ [-Wreorder]
./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:55:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
In file included from ./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:36:0:
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:131:17: warning: ‘GLBatch::pTexCoords’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:115:11: warning:   ‘GLuint GLBatch::uiVertexArray’ [-Wreorder]
./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:55:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
In file included from ./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:36:0:
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:125:14: warning: ‘GLBatch::bBatchDone’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:121:16: warning:   ‘GLuint GLBatch::nVertsBuilding’ [-Wreorder]
./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:55:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
In file included from ./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:36:0:
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:121:16: warning: ‘GLBatch::nVertsBuilding’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
./libs/include/GLBatch.h:118:12: warning:   ‘GLuint* GLBatch::uiTextureCoordArray’ [-Wreorder]
./libs/src/GLBatch.cpp:55:1: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
./libs/src/GLShaderManager.cpp:481:8: warning: unused parameter ‘szVertexProg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
./libs/src/GLShaderManager.cpp:481:8: warning: unused parameter ‘szFragProg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
```

I'm afraid if I disable those specific warnings ( `-Wunused-parameter` and `-Wreorder` ), they might happen in my own code in which case I would be told about it.  I'm a beginner at C++ so I'd like to have all the help the compiler can give me to identify my errors, or things I might do that are bad practice.

Comment: I have no idea.  How about telling us what the warnings say?

Comment: with g++ you can tell the compiler that that directory contains standard headers. i don't recall the option for that. check it out'

Comment: Possibly use `-w` flag for the codes not in the src directory. Tell makefile to use `-w` not in the src directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us your makefile, but I suppose it looks something like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Otherflags

MYOBJECTS = obj/foo.o obj/bar.o  # from sources in src/
LIBOBJECTS = obj/baz.o obj/quartz.o  # from sources in lib/
OBJECTS = $(MYOBJECTS) $(LIBOBJECTS)

executable: $(OBJECTS)
    ...

obj/%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

vpath %.cc src lib
```

If so, just add a [target-specific variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
CFLAGS = -Otherflags

$(MYOBJECTS): CFLAGS += -Wall
```

Comment: My makefile is so ugly (I'm learning how to do them as I'm doing this) I didn't dare including it.  But it pretty much does what yours does.  I'll try it out (and try to clean up my Makefile at the same time)!

Answer (score 2):

you may use `-isystem` option instead of `-include` for path that contains include files of your library. Then you probably will see warnings only when lib is compiled itself. inclusion of these files in your source files will not cause warnings

Answer (score -1):

AntoineG - The warnings are for a reason. Fix the code.

Comment: You mean I should fix the book author's code?  I'd like to learn the technology and fix my own code first.

Comment: @AntoineG - fixing the book author's code can help learn the technology. Depends on the book, though. <g>